# Dicky-Fuller test and Stationarity

Tags: time-series, unit-root, augmented-dickey-fuller

[image][image]On a periodic (365 days) data, I ran dicky fuller test and that shows it is stationary. However ACF plot does not show a geometric decay, I think that is because of periodicity, Is it stationary or I am missing something here?

```
    Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test

data:  min_temp_aus
Dickey-Fuller = -5.2386, Lag order = 15, p-value = 0.01
alternative hypothesis: stationary

Warning message:
In adf.test(min_temp_aus) : p-value smaller than printed p-value
```

Comment: This is hard to say as it stands, it would be helpful to include a plot of the time series or other pertinent information.

Comment: Using Acf in forecast package gives a sin wave, I did not know which one was more helpful!